# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]

Tags: out-of-gas

What is this ? I am trying to send a transaction from my Nano S Ledger to a Bittrex Account dont understand what is happening ? Do I need to purchase Gas as well ???

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x32fc78fa8a7074d98cd0e32005b7485a44af1423e688637f55c3ce573b150d78

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction was successfully mined, i.e. included into blockchain by miners, but its execution failed due to insufficient gas.  Gas is a measure of execution complexity in Ethereum.  When you send a transaction you specify two gas-related parameters: "gas limit" and "gas price".  Gas limit is how much gas you allow your transaction to spend during execution.  Gas price is how many Wei (1 Wei = 10^-18 Ether) you are going to pay for each gas unit.  Total fee you may have to pay for your transaction execution is limited by gas limit times gas price Wei.

Everything transaction is doing, costs some gas.  The simplest possible transaction, that just transfers some Ether from one externally owned address (i.e. plain, non smart contract address) to another, that does not bear any extra data, and does not lead to execution of any byte code, costs 21000 gas.  This amount is known as intrinsic gas cost: it is charged for the sole fact of a transaction to be executed.

Every byte of additional data included into transaction costs additional gas.  Every byte code instruction executed with transaction also spends some gas.

For you transaction, gas limit was set to 21,000, and gas price was 21,000,000,000 Wei (0.000000021 Ether) per gas unit.  You transaction does not have any data attached, but destination address is a smart contract, rather than externally owned address: [0xa0380ee140befb7f0c055d5fc06702f3546cbbea](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0380ee140befb7f0c055d5fc06702f3546cbbea).  This means that execution of your transaction implies execution of the code of this contract.  Thus, gas limit of 21,000 is definitely too low for your transaction.  It covers only intrinsic gas cost, but does not cover byte code execution.

As you can see, similar transactions that were executed successfully, consumed 21,051 gas per transaction: [0x5ddaacaf3d2fb3093018b085a9e82083b36e688d316ab82465cd1cb9d073dabb](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5ddaacaf3d2fb3093018b085a9e82083b36e688d316ab82465cd1cb9d073dabb), [0xff10f9c4d7e17c4eb6ed10f28ffd486bfe20a81e093992bc367d9f42f3dedbcc](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xff10f9c4d7e17c4eb6ed10f28ffd486bfe20a81e093992bc367d9f42f3dedbcc) etc.

So, basically what you should do is to resend your transaction with higher gas limit, probably 21,051 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending to a contract address. The gas limit 21000 in your transaction is too low. Older successful transaction have a gas limit of 90000.

You should look at Bittrex documentation, ask their support which value to use for gas limit.